# Validate uploaded file for jpg and png and save to static folder

Tags: java, file-upload

I am using spring boot and I want to upload an image via a form.

It works, but there are 2 problems:

1) I do not know how to validate the file to make sure it is either `jpg` or `png`

2) I can upload only to the `root` folder, not to the `static` folder, I do not know how to set the correct path to the `resources/static` folder

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@Valid Product product, @RequestParam MultipartFile file, BindingResult bindingResult,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
...

try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes(); // how to validate this?
            Path path = Paths.get( file.getOriginalFilename()); // how to set path here?
            Files.write(path, bytes);

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!! Image uploaded problem !!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get file extension

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
```

Path

```
 InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
 File destination = new File("/some-location/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
 FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(in, destination);
```